# Get HTML subtree from HTMLparser

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing

I'm actually working with HTMLparser for python, i'm trying to get a HTML subtree contained in a specific node.
I have a generic parser doing its job well, and once the interesting tag found, I would like to feed another specific HTMLParser with the data in this node.

This is an example of what i want to do :

```
class genericParser(HTMLParser):
   def __init__ (self):
       HTMLParser.__init__(self)
       self.divFound = False

   def handle_starttag (self, tag, attrs):
       if tag == "div" and ("class", "good") in attrs:
           self.divFound = True

   def handle_data (self, data):
       if self.divFound:
           print data    ## print nothing
           parser = specificParser ()
           parser.feed (data)
           self.divFound = False
```

and feed the genericParser with something like :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <div class='good'>
      <ul>
         <li>test1</li>
         <li>test2</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but in the python documentation of HTMLParser.handle_data :

> This method is called to process arbitrary data (e.g. text nodes and
>   the content of `<script>...</script>` and `<style>...</style>`).

In my `genericParser`, the data got in `handle_data` is empty because my `<div class='good'>` isn't a text node.

How can I retrieve the raw HTML data inner my div using HTMLParser ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be easier to use a `DOM` parser to extract a subtree. Are you stuck with `HTMLParser`?

Comment: I tried to use the HTMLParser because a big part of the project is already done with it, and I found this problem to parse subtree. Finally I start recording the html tree in a buffer, to use it at the `handle_endtag()` ending the interesting block. It's not the solution I thought, but i'm not stuck anymore. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: So, have you already solved it?

Comment: Yes, i'm going to answer with the solution, but i wait few hours to see if there is a better solution than buffering the html.

Comment: I asked you because was thinking in extracting the subtree with `BeautifulSoup` and then call your *specificParser*. If you were stuck with `HTMLParser` my idea was also to record each node until the closing `</div>` but I see you have been already working on it.

Comment: @Birei : Unfortunately yes i'm stuck with the HTMLParser because my GenericParser is big, and it's must be a waste of time to rewrite it using BeautifulSoup. I should have done more research before starting the developement. Thanks a lot for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem by buffering all data encountered in the interesting HTML node.

This one works but isn't very "clean" because the GenericParser has to parse the whole interesting block before fed the SpecificParser with it.
Here is a "light" (without any errors handling) solution :

```
class genericParser(HTMLParser):
   def __init__ (self):
       HTMLParser.__init__ (self)
       self.divFound = False
       self.buff = ""
       self.level = 0

   def computeRecord (self, tag, attrs):
        mystr = "<" + tag + " "
        for att, val in attrs:
            mystr += att+"='"+val+ "' "
        mystr += ">"
        return mystr

   def handle_starttag (self, tag, attrs):
       if tag == "div" and ("class", "good") in attrs:
           self.divFound = True
       elif self.divFound:
          self.level += 1
          self.buff += self.computeRecord (tag, attrs)

   def handle_data (self, data):
       if self.divFound:
          self.buff += data


   def handle_endtag (self, tag):
      if self.divFound:
         self.buff += "</" + tag + ">"
         self.level -= 1
         if (self.level == 0):
            self.divFound = False
            print self.buff
```

The output is as desired :

```
<ul>
     <li>test1</li>
     <li>test2</li>
</ul>
```

As Birei said in comments, i would have been easier to extract the subtree with BeautifulSoup

```
soup = BeaufitulSoup (html)
div = soup("div", {"class" : "good"})
children = div[0].findChildren ()
print children[0]   #### desired output
```